# Kibana is not working after port change

Tags: kibana, elastic-stack

I change Kibana port from 5601 to 80 in kibana.yml file.
I restarted kibana after the change, but I didn't work. 
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

The ports 0-1023 are the "well-known ports" and reserved, so you need higher privileges to bind to one of that port.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the port 80 is vacant without being used by any other process?

Does `elasticsearch` work after the change you made in the `Kibana` yml? Because you need `elasticsearch` for `Kibana` to be up and running. Make sure you're pointing to the correct domain.

If you're getting any errors on the `Kibana` console, put it up here so that it will be useful to resolve.

Source: [setting up kibana](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/setup.html)